# Getting an error missing Parse error. missing ) after argument list at

Tags: jquery

I have been getting this error Parse error. missing ) after argument list at

The code that i am using is

```
setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide('fast', function() {document.getElementById("Form1").submit();});", 200);
```

Not been able to figure the error. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1) passing a string to `setTimeout` is a bad idea, because 1a) it's much slower, and 1b) you lose syntax highlighting. And so do we.

Comment: even code snippet you wrote shows you have an incorrect syntax related with single/double quotes.

Comment: @EnterJQ your edit "breaks" the code. Multiline strings are invalid in javascript. Reverting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quotes within quotes - you need to escape them.

Better still, avoid evaluated JavaScript and pass your code as a callback to `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#suggestions').hide('fast', function() {
        document.getElementById("Form1").submit();
    });
}, 200);
```

Comment: Not sure - seemed a valid question and decently presented. Downvotes without explanation are one of SO's worse aspects.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $('#suggestions').hide('fast', function() {
        document.getElementById('Form1').submit();
    });
}, 200);
```

Comment: I'll take care next time, Thanks :)